# Postgres/JDBC/Logical replication - out of memory issues

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, change-data-capture, debezium

I am developing an application which connects to a logical replication slot, to consume the WAL events. These WAL events are then forwarded to a MQ broker. This works great, but I noticed that I am running out of memory after some time. I managed to minimize the problem to the code responsible for getting the WAL events. It occurs with the following code:

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();

PGProperty.USER.set(properties, "user");
PGProperty.PASSWORD.set(properties, "password");
PGProperty.ASSUME_MIN_SERVER_VERSION.set(properties, "9.4");
PGProperty.REPLICATION.set(properties, "database");
PGProperty.PREFER_QUERY_MODE.set(properties, "simple");

while (true) {
    Connection          connection   = null;
    PGConnection        PGConnection = null;
    PGReplicationStream stream       = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db", properties);
        PGConnection = connection.unwrap(PGConnection.class);
        stream = PGConnection.getReplicationAPI().replicationStream().logical().withSlotName("slot").start();

        while (true) {
            final ByteBuffer buffer = stream.read();

            // ... logic here ... (disabled during memory test)

            stream.setAppliedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
            stream.setFlushedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
        }
    } catch (final SQLException e1) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error(e1);

        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (final SQLException e2) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error(e2);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (final SQLException e2) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error(e2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I commented out the logic to parse the message and forward it to the MQ broker, as the out of memory also occurs without this.

I also tried to alter this example by using the polling method `readPending()` instead of the blocking method `read()` (as shown at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html), but the problem remains.

I also noticed that after a while, the application comes in a 100% CPU usage. This must be caused by the underlying libraries, as the `read()` is still processing normally at that moment (that is, it processes each WAL event sequentially).

During these tests, I am executing `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries, at a low rate.

I am using following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The application runs as a WAR in a Tomcat8 container.

Any idea what is going on?

**update 1**

I figured out what is going on, but cannot explain it so far. I'll go in details.

Every 10 seconds, I do `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries, as said. These queries result in 645 WAL events.  So every 10 seconds, I have to `read()` 645 events. In the beginning, this takes 0 (or sometimes 1) milliseconds to `read()` one event. After some time, it takes 1 milliseconds. Then, again some time later, it takes 2 milliseconds. And so on...

So after a while, I am unable to `read()` 645 events in 10 seconds, as the time required to `read()` keeps increasing. This explains the 100% CPU usage and the out of memory.

I am still unsure how to explain and how to fix this. I will keep investigating.

**update 2**

I tried adding `buffer.clear()` at the end of the loop, without success. I am still running into 100% CPU and memory issues. This is as expected, because the buffer is a local variable, so it's GC'ed after each loop any way. But I thought it would be a good idea to test anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why I was running out of memory. I was testing with the `decoderbufs` decoding output plugin, https://github.com/xstevens/decoderbufs. When replacing by the built-in `test` plugin or `wal2json` (https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json), I am not having these problems.

I will try to inform the author of the `decoderbufs` plugin.